# HAPROXY roundrobin DNS on backend server domain

Tags: reverse-proxy, haproxy

I have read allot of posts and tried several things, but can't seem to get what I want working and stable.

I have HAproxy setup as a pure proxy. The IP/domain of the HAproxy passes ALL to the backend server.

My issues is that the backend server domain has 2 IPs in DNS:

1.1.1.1
2.2.2.2

When the provider switches or removes an IP, HAproxy does not update to the "new" IP and gives a backend not reachable error in the logs:

Message from syslogd@localhost at Jul 18 16:15:02 ...
 haproxy[3233]: backend b-http has no server available!

But there is a valid and working server on one of the ips. A restart which forces HAproxy to do a lookup normally fixes this, but I'd prefer for it to be automatic.

On HAproxy version haproxy-1.5.18 I have:

frontend f-http
    bind :80
    default_backend b-http

backend b-http
    option forwardfor
    server web-1 domain.com:80 check

I have tried on HAproxy version haproxy-1.7.8-1 I have:

resolvers public-dns
        nameserver dns2 8.8.8.8:53
        nameserver dns1 8.8.4.4:53
    hold valid           10s

frontend f-http
    bind :80
    default_backend b-http

backend b-http
    option forwardfor
server web-1 domain.com:80 resolvers public-dns check

As above dig on domain.com would return 2 A records. I'm thinking that there must be some config which will continue to check the IPs for a valid/working IP and start to use that one on the fly.

Any help is very much appreciated.